# Jordan decomposition of a normal linear functional

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Suppose that $\rho$ is a normal linear functional on $M$.
We have the Jordan decomposition :$\rho=\omega_{+}-\omega_{-}$ and $\|\rho\|=\|\omega_{+}\|+\|\omega_{-}\|$, where $\omega_{+}$ and $\omega_{-}$ are positive normal functionals on $M$ with orthogonal supports $e$ and $f$.

My question:
1.Can we express $\omega_{+}$ in terms of $\rho$?

2.Is there any relationship between the support of $\omega_{+}$ and the support of $\rho$?

3. I think the above decomposition is not true for zero linear functional.

Answer (score 1):

$\rho$ has to be Hermitian in addition to normal.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'express', but I think $e$ is the supremum of all projections $E$ in $M$ such that $x\mapsto \rho(ExE)$ is positive definite.  Then $\rho_+ (x) = \rho(e x e)$.  Similary $f$ is the supremum of all projections $F$ in $M$ such that $x \mapsto -\rho(FxF)$ is positive definite and $\rho_-(x) = -\rho(fxf)$.  The support of $\rho$ is $e+f$.  For your last question if $\rho = 0$ then $e=f=0$ and $\rho_+ = \rho_- = 0$.  It is not required that $e+f = I$.

Edit: by positive definite I mean that $ExE \ge 0 \implies \rho(ExE)\ge 0$ and if additionally $ExE \ne 0$ then $\rho(ExE) > 0$.

Comment: But how to decompose $\rho_1-\rho_2$ if $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are positive linear functional?  We decompse $\rho_1$ as following: $\rho_1=\rho_1^{+}-\rho_1^{-}$. Because $\rho_1$ is positive, we have $\rho_1^{+}=\rho$ and $\rho_1^{-}=0$. Similarly, we have $\rho_2=\rho_2^{+}-\rho_2^{-}$, where $\rho_2^{+}=\rho_2$,$\rho_2^{-}=0$.  Then $\rho_1-\rho_2=\rho_1^{+}-\rho_2^{+}$, but the support of $\rho_1^{+}$ may not be orthogonal to the support of $\rho_2^{+}$.

Comment: @mathbeginner:  There's no generic answer to that because it depends on the supports of $\rho_1, \rho_2$ you started with.

Comment: If the supports are both 1. How to get the decomposition?

Comment: @mathbeginner:  I don't know.  Two projections $e_1, e_2$ are considered compatible if they commute $e_1 e_2 = e_2 e_1$ and then $e_1 e_2$ is the projection on the intersection and $e_1 + e_2 - e_1 e_2$ is the projection on the sum.  But if you start from arbitrary $\rho_1, \rho_2$ - the supports of their $\pm$ parts may not be compatible so I don't know how to do what you're asking.  If all supports are compatible there is a solution.